# Android, animate image up and back down

Tags: android, image, animation

I'm trying to animate image starting bellow screen, going up, and then back down (doing app for Galaxy tab).
Both of these animations work separately, but when I try to create AnimationSet, I can't get them to work.
I even tried creating 2 AsyncTasks, and call 2nd animation in onPostExecute of the 1st AsyncTask, but still won't work.

this is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
   >
    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ad200"
        android:id="@+id/image"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my code I'm trying to use to animate image:

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 1024, 824);
anim1.setDuration(3000);
anim1.setFillAfter(true);
set.addAnimation(anim1);

Animation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 824, 1024);
anim2.setDuration(3000);
anim2.setFillAfter(true);
set.addAnimation(anim2);

imageView.clearAnimation();
set.setFillAfter(true);
imageView.startAnimation(set);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well WendiKidd,

You are very close to your solution. You have just missed the Animation.AnimationListener() in your Code.

```
Animation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 1024, 824);
anim1.setDuration(3000);
anim1.setFillAfter(true);

anim1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Animation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 824, 1024);
                anim2.setDuration(3000);
                anim2.setFillAfter(true);
                imageView.clearAnimation();
                imageView.startAnimation(anim2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });


imageView.startAnimation(anim1);
```

The sample above will start anim2 after anim1 ends.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are starting both animations at the same time. Add anim2.setStartOffset(3000) to your second animation. That will cause the second animation to start 3000 ms after the first one.

BR,
Christoffer

Comment: I have tried that already, I still only get black screen, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a solution...try this below code.. i use this code so many times .. and it works fine..======>

```
    Animation zoomin =new TranslateAnimation(1, 1, 0, -50);
    zoomin.setDuration(1000);
    zoomin.setFillEnabled(true);
    zoomin.setFillAfter(true);

    Animation zoomout =  new TranslateAnimation(1, 1, -50, 0);
    zoomout.setDuration(1000);
    zoomout.setFillEnabled(true);
    zoomout.setFillAfter(true);

    imageView.startAnimation(zoomin);

    zoomin.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            imageView.startAnimation(zoomout);
          }
    });

    zoomout.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

            imageView.startAnimation(zoomin);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers are too complicated and can be written in simpler manner.

Kotlin solution looks like this:

```
val animation: Animation = TranslateAnimation(0F, 0F, 0F, -100F)
    animation.duration = 3000
    animation.fillAfter = true
    animation.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
    animation.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE
```

Main variables set here are:

`animation.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE`

`animation.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE`

I'm guessing that you want to animate something to go up and down (or left and right) all the time, so you can use `animation.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE` and if you want the animation to return to the previous position instead of going from up to down, then resetting its position, use `animation.repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE`